# Ref question: K-nearest neighbours in a graph

Tags: reference-request, shortest-path

Given an undirected  graph $G$  with $n$ vertices,  $m$ edges, and positive weights on the edges, I am interested in the problem of computing for each vertex the $k$ distinct vertices in $G$ that are closest to it on the shortest-path distances in $G$. There is a solution that follows by modifying Dijkstra, where the running time is $k$ times the running time of the standard Dijkstra. Anybody knows a ref to this result? Should I bother to write this down?

thanks....

**Update:** I wrote down my algorithm in case anybody is interested... 
http://sarielhp.org/p/14/k_nn/

Comment: Nice, but why would you need to compute KNN? You can get better statistical and algorithmic performance out of an appropriately regularized 1-NN.

Comment: I have no clue what "appropriately regularized 1-NN" is. Ref?

Comment: A. Kontorovich, Roi Weiss. A Bayes consistent 1-NN classifier, to appear in AISTATS 2015. https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3198145/bayes-consistent-1nn.pdf

Comment: That was the statistical part. The algorithmic one is here:

Comment: L. Gottlieb, A. Kontorovich, P. Nisnevitch. Near-optimal sample compression for nearest neighbors, NIPS 2014.
http://arxiv.org/pdf/1404.3368v3.pdf

Comment: Well, you should probably check out section 7 in this paper. http://sarielhp.org/p/12/kann/

Naturally, removing points if they are not necessary for answering ANN queries is a natural approach to thin out data...

Comment: Interesting. Do these results extend to doubling spaces?

Comment: Some of the stuff do...

Answer (score 2):

In [Victor Teixeira de Almeida, Ralf Hartmut Güting: Using Dijkstra's algorithm to incrementally find the k-Nearest Neighbors in spatial network databases. SAC 2006: 58-62](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?doid=1141277.1141291), Teixeira and Güting describe a new storage schema with a set of indexed structures to support an efficient
execution of a slightly modified version of the Dijkstra's algorithm.

In the introduction they simply use the reference to the original Dijkstra's paper:

... An obvious modification on Dijkstra's algorithm 
[*reference to the original Dijkstra's 1967 paper*] that computes shortest path between objects could be done in order to compute the k-NN using the network space.
But, in this case, sepcial storage schemas are necessary in order to
efficiently support this algorithm. In this paper, ...

So I think you can use the same approach: if your work is NOT focused on a new variant of a k-NN algorithm you can simply mention it and cite Dijkstra's paper; otherwise you should also include other references on the subject; I think there are many of them because the k-NN problem is important, for example, in navigation systems; googling around I found: Fast Nearest Neighbor Search on Road Networks, Alternative Solutions for Continuous K-NN Queries in Spatial Network Databases, ...

Comment: Yeh - I run across the same thing when doing web search. However, since they do not give details, I have no clue what they are referring to. What I am asking for is for a reference that describes how to do the k-NN in detail using Dijkstra, including exact running time analysis - see it is not totally obvious.

Answer (score 0):

This paper:

> Man Lung Yiu, Dimitris Papadias, Nikos Mamoulis, Yufei Tao: Reverse
>   Nearest Neighbors in Large Graphs. IEEE Trans. Knowl. Data Eng. 18(4):
>   540-553 (2006)

calculates the `kNN` of each vertex belonging to the target set. The proof can be found on Section 4.1 and algorithm `All-NN(k)`.